# How can I convert an array of object to an array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects:

```
jobs: {
      tasks:
        {
          Clean:[
            {time: "08:00", task: 'floor 1'},
            {time: "09:00", task: 'floor 2'}
          ],

          Print:[
            {time: "10:00", task: 'x files'},
            {time: "11:00", task: 'x files 2.0'}
          ]                      

        }
  }
```

I need to convert the data to something like this

```
 this.listTimeJob.Clean = ['','','','','','','', '','floor 1','floor 2','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''];
 this.listTimeJob.Print = ['','','','','','','','','','','x files','x files 2.0','','','','','','','','','','','','',''];
```

so I can loop through and have as a result
[image]

I'm really stuck with this, I still trying to figure this out.. if anybody can give a little help I really appreciate..

Comment: Please include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. That would really help us to figure out the issue with your code.

Comment: Well you don't need to convert it, you just need to loop from 0 to 23 and see if that period lies within either of the objects properties. (having 00:00 and 24:00 is a bit odd too)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce`, pass accumulator as `Array(24).fill("")` and with each iteration change the value of accumulator's index based on the time value.

```
var cleanData = data.jobs.tasks.Clean.reduce(
  (acc, el, i) => {
    var index = +el.time.split(":")[0];
    acc[index] = el.task;
    return acc;
  }, Array(24).fill("")
);
```

```js
var data = {
  jobs: {
    tasks: {
      Clean: [{
          time: "08:00",
          task: 'floor 1'
        },
        {
          time: "09:00",
          task: 'floor 2'
        }
      ],

      Print: [{
          time: "10:00",
          task: 'x files'
        },
        {
          time: "11:00",
          task: 'x files 2.0'
        }
      ]

    }
  }
}

var cleanData = data.jobs.tasks.Clean.reduce(
  (acc, el, i) => {
    var index = +el.time.split(":")[0];
    acc[index] = el.task;
    return acc;
  }, Array(24).fill("")
);

var printData = data.jobs.tasks.Print.reduce(
  (acc, el, i) => {
    var index = +el.time.split(":")[0];
    acc[index] = el.task;
    return acc;
  }, Array(24).fill("")
);

console.log(cleanData);
console.log(printData)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create two arrays with all the empty data in them then loop through your tasks and get the time to use as the index:

```
this.listTimeJob.Clean = [];
this.listTimeJob.Print = [];

for (var x = 0; x < 25; x++) {
    this.listTimeJob.Clean.push("");
    this.listTimeJob.Print.push("");
}

for (var y = 0; y < jobs.tasks.Clean.length; y++){
    var index = parseInt(jobs.tasks.Clean[y].time.split(":"), 10);
    this.listTimeJob.Clean[index] = jobs.tasks.Clean[y].task
}

for (var y = 0; y < jobs.tasks.Print.length; y++){
    var index = parseInt(jobs.tasks.Print[y].time.split(":"), 10);
    this.listTimeJob.Print[index] = jobs.tasks.Print[y].task
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My plain JS version

```js
var jobs = {
      tasks:
        {
          Clean:[
            {time: "08:00", task: 'floor 1'},
            {time: "09:00", task: 'floor 2'}
          ],

          Print:[
            {time: "10:00", task: 'x files'},
            {time: "11:00", task: 'x files 2.0'}
          ]                      

        }
  }
 
function pad(num) {
  return ("0"+num).slice(-2);
} 
var th = document.querySelector("#th"),
    tb = document.querySelector("#tb"),
    time=[], 
    clean = new Array(24), 
    print = new Array(24), 
    tasks=jobs.tasks;

for (var i=0;i<24;i++) { // from 00:00 to 23:00
  time.push(""+pad(i)+":00")
}  
for (var j=0;j<tasks.Clean.length;j++) {
  clean[parseInt(tasks.Clean[j].time)]=tasks.Clean[j].task;
}
for (var j=0;j<tasks.Print.length;j++) {
  print[parseInt(tasks.Print[j].time)]=tasks.Print[j].task;
}

th.innerHTML="<tr><th>"+time.join("</th><th>")+"</th></tr>";
tb.innerHTML="<tr><td>"+clean.join("</td><td>")+"</td></tr>";
tb.innerHTML+="<tr><td>"+print.join("</td><td>")+"</td></tr>";
```

```css
td { border:1px solid black }
```

```html
<table>
<thead id="th"></thead>
<tbody id="tb"></tbody>
</table>
```